# jQuery - Why rangelength rule of form validation plugin doesn't work for FILE

Tags: jquery

I try to use the following rule to limit the length of the uploaded file. However, it doesn't work for me. In the other hands, I can validate the extension of the uploaded file by using accept rule.

uFile: { accept: "jpg|jpeg|gif|png|tiff", rangelength: [5, 7] }

jQuery Form Validation http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Is there a way that I can do this with this plugin or I just cannot do it?

Thank you